# Quick question on orthogonal subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with a bilinear form defined on it.

let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$. Then $U \subset W^{\perp} \iff W \subset U^{\perp}$.

Why is this? maybe one can prove one direction and I will try to prove the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $U\subset W^\perp$ and let $w\in W$. Then $\langle w,\hat{w}\rangle = 0$ for all $\hat{w}\in W^\perp$. Since $U\subset W^\perp$ it follows that $\langle w,u\rangle = 0$ for all $u\in U$, which implies that $w\in U^\perp$. Since $w$ is arbitrary, it follows that $W\subset U^\perp$.

Comment: Thank you K. Miller, so bilinearity is never used?

Comment: I used $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ as my bilinear form, but I probably should have been more explicit about this with my notation.